# Logstash Cloudwatch input plugin not returning any data in the message field

Tags: amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, logstash, kibana, amazon-cloudwatch

I'm using
Logstash - 7.9.0

```
Input Config - 
  cloudwatch {
    namespace  => "AWS/Lambda"
    type       => "cloudwatch_lambda"
    metrics    => [ "Duration", "Errors" ]
    tags       => [ "application-logs", "lambda-metric-logs" ]
    statistics => ["Average"]
    filters    => { "FunctionName" => "<name_of_the_function>" }
    interval   => 900
    region     => "$REGION"
  }
```

Output -

```
{
    "level": "INFO",
    "loggerName": "logstash.inputs.cloudwatch",
    "timeMillis": 1606241295784,
    "thread": "[main]<cloudwatch",
    "logEvent": {
        "message": "[Aws::CloudWatch::Client 200 0.066722 0 retries] get_metric_statistics(namespace:\"AWS/Lambda\",metric_name:\"Duration\",start_time:2020-11-24 17:53:15 UTC,end_time:2020-11-24 18:08:15 UTC,period:300,statistics:[\"Average\"],dimensions:[{name:\"FunctionName\",value:\"[FILTERED]\"}])  \n"
    }
}
```

The output doesn't return any data in the message field

Comment: You have chosen to return `Duration` and `Errors` metrics from the `AWS/Lambda` namespace. That's exactly what the `logEvent.message` field contains. You'd just need to parse that string. What are you expecting instead?

Comment: I don't see any value for the duration

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue but with AWS/EC2 namespace. Removing the Interval fixed it for me.

intervaled
Value type is number
Default value is 900
Set how frequently CloudWatch should be queried

The default, 900, means check every 15 minutes. Setting this value too low (generally less than 300) results in no metrics being returned from CloudWatch.